# When I run nav mesh in Unity 3d, something called exporting tiles appears and takes too long

Tags: unity-game-engine, navigation, nav, game-development, navmesh

I want to design artificial intelligence with unity. I have an island and a sea in my game. I baked the sea as navigation for ships at sea to attack the island. but in this way it makes me wait for unbelievable times. it wasn't like this before, does anyone know the solution?

I want to design artificial intelligence with unity. I have an island and a sea in my game. I baked the sea as navigation for ships at sea to attack the island. but in this way it makes me wait for unbelievable times. it wasn't like this before, does anyone know the solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gx3W.jpg)

edit : I finally solved it. Friends, the problem was that the terrain or the ground was large. Try shrinking the floor!

[SOLVED]

Comment: If it was better before did you do any changes that could affect the performance and size of your game.

Comment: @MaximilianFischerno, I did not . My game is already 85 mb in total even when I build a mobile game. nav mesh didn't work even though I waited 4 hours . I don't understand why this is happening...

Comment: This is not a forum. Please remove the second duplicated paragraph. Then post your solution as an answer an accept it. Also remove the [SOLVED].